# Box Muller vs Numpy?

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, numpy

I used the [Box Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) and pythons uniform random number generator to sample random numbers in a given interval [a,b]. Here's the approach I used:

Note: I know the average and the standard deviation.

```
a = mean - 3*std_dev         
b = mean + 3*std_dev
summa = 0
begin loop 
   generate 2 random numbers r1, r2
   run function to calculate the Box Mueller transform (z1, z2)
   a1 = a + (b-a)*z1
   a2 = a + (b-a)*z2
   summa = summa + a1 + a2
end loop after 1000 samples
find average of summa
```

**

I do this twice since I need to calculate 2 values (namely voltage and current) for two different values of mean and standard deviation. This is then used to calculate resistance R and its deviation from a given value.

Now, I tried this with the [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) sampling approach. To my surprise, my values were about +0.08 off. Numpy gave me a value closer to the mean. 
My question is that whether this is should be expected, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Strongly related thread on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: You may be seeing nothing more than random variation on such a small sample. Try the output of a number of such runs for both. Are they substantively different (are their means or sd's very different?)

Comment: @Glen_b Turns out that the Box Mueller function returns negative numbers as well. Should I return it as an absolute value? Also, to answer your previous question, increasing the sample size didn't help but if I return the absolute values, the sample average is closer to the mean. Is this the right approach though?

Comment: @Tim I see your point but I don't think floating point accuracy was the real issue. The sampled average was no where close to what must be expected and that's why I asked the question.

Comment: user165971 Box-Mueller returns standard normal random values... so *of course* about half should be negative. What did you think it did? Are you trying to compare it with uniforms?